# Как написать слово "щи" в единственном числе?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как написать слово ЩИ в единственном числе: Щ или ЩЬ?

Answer (score 3):

Слово "щи" не употребляется в единственном числе. Точно также, как "ножницы", "штаны" или "бигуди".

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы не ЩА?

Слово ЩИ не имеет единственного числа.  Так же как, например, брюки или дрова.
Более того, грамматический род не определяется даже по косвенным признакам.
Поэтому на ваш вопрос нельзя ответить даже со всеми возможными оговорками.

Answer (score 1):

Перед нами пример существительных pluralia tantum - всегда множественного числа. По мнению Соболевского, щи восходят к др-рус. *съти*, а *съти* - к слову *съть* (*сътъ*), имевшему значение "питательный напиток". Оно это родственно таким словам, как *соты, сытый, сосать*.
(В этимологии, впрочем, многое спорно.)

Answer (score 0):

Щец.

Хотелось бы уточнить, что европейский суп и славянский щец - совсем не родственники.

Европейский суп -- это бульон оставшийся от варки основного блюда для сеньора и в него добавлено то, что сеньор так и не доел, жиденькое и в нем что то плавает... Еда слуг.

Шец -- это вареное всяко разное, кто чего принес... В щах, борщах, шурпе и прочих подобных кушаньях конечно есть юшка... но ложка в нем должна стоять! Еда свободных и равных.

Поскольку щи готовятся скопом из всего, то в принципе и не должно быть единственного числа... но такое слово всё таки есть, я его знаю и слышал от людей не переотягощенных книжным знанием.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Думается мне, что зря Вы поставили точку после "Щец". Скорее всего, это попытка оформления заглавия. Да и "ни хрена" можно было оставить — как разговорно-сниженную особенность авторского языка. (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/278035/%D0%BD%D0%B8) Прошу — без обид!

Comment: ЩЕЦ. Разг. Ласк. форма род. п. к **щи** (другие падежи не употр.). https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%86 Нельзя писать "славянский щец" — это ошибка. У В. Гиляровского: _Придет. Сядет. Подзовет полового: — **Вчерашних щец** кухонных осталось?_ P. S.Очень хочется, чтобы Вы все-таки отяготились знаниями — хотя бы пунктуационными: в Вашем ответе не хватает двух дефисов и шести запятых.