# Ещё раз про "щи", которые "суп"

Tags: словообразование, семантика

Вопрос не про этимологию, я видел вопрос от 2017 года, Фасмера прочитал и т. д.

Для удобства вот ссылка на тот вопрос: [В: Этимология слова “щи”](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/19129/%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%89%d0%b8?r=SearchResults&s=2|37.0136), и чуть-чуть есть здесь: [Как написать слово “щи” в единственном числе?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%89%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5)

А вопрос такой: "Почему щи назвали во множественном числе, ведь это суп?" (*Я здесь самую малость упростил и сократил.*)

Задала мне его иностранка, **свободно говорящая по-русски**.

С ходу я не ответил, да и обстановка не располагала, но пообещал подумать и ответить позже.

Я не ответил с ходу, наверное, потому, что для меня эта "множественность" (вот, подсказали термин - **"собирательность"**) совершенно естественна и никакого противоречия я в ней не чувствую и не вижу.

Поиск в Интернете, и про этимологию в том числе, привёл к статье, где перечислены примеры "подобных" слов, по памяти: **помои** (*да, забавно*), **белила**, **румяна**, и что-то ещё... забыл.

**Обновлено**: белила, дрожжи, дрова, духи, консервы, макароны, опилки, отруби, сливки, чернила и т. д.

Мне было бы интересно послушать ваши варианты ответа на этот вопрос. А также как бы вы сформулировали, какое общее свойство всех вышеперечисленных понятий привело их к существованию только во мн. ч.

Если это кому-то интересно, разумеется.

**Добавлено #1**
Читаю сейчас интересное исследование [Щи на Русском Севере. Культурно-языковая символика](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/schi-na-russkom-severe-kulturno-yazykovaya-simvolika). Правда, вопрос мн. ч. там не затрагивается...

**Добавлено #2**
Продолжаю эпизодически возвращаться к этой теме, работа и пр. не позволяют уделить достаточно времени, к сожалению. 
Пока для меня остаётся открытым вопрос: что аттестовано раньше "кислые щи"(напиток) или "шти/щи" (суп, похлёбка, варево)?

Я практически уверен, что второе (и это первая причина, по которой я не принимаю ответ @behemothus), просто не искал пока никаких тому подтверждений. Где-то в первых же ссылках попадалось, что "шти" (суп) известно по письменным источникам с начала XVI века, капуста там не упоминается и "скорее всего суп был из рыбы"... А вот про "напиток" никаких хронологических данных не встречалось. Кто сможет с этим помочь, сэкономит мне время.)

Ну а вторая причина, по которой я не принимаю ответ, состоит в том, что я внутренне не согласен с отсутствием в этом слове собирательности, а также не вижу веских причин **не** ставить его в один ряд с "помои", "отруби", "сливки".

Другое дело, что железобетонных аргументов - как "за", так и "против" - мы, возможно, так и не найдём. Но ничего страшного в этом нет.

**Добавлено #3**
Нда, "кислые щи" (напиток) упоминаются в "Домострое", который условно датируется тоже XVI веком +/- лапоть. Все остальные письменные свидельства - из пушкинских времен и позднее.

Попытка дилетантского исследования зашла в тупик.
Зато удалось выяснить, что Интернет битком набит ... цитатами из Интернета. :)

Т.е.: статья из Фасмана "щи" и три-четыре цитаты из Достоевского/Ключевского или кого там про "кислые шти" (из википедии) вставляются (для солидности) буквально везде, иногда подредактированные автором. Затем следуют какие-то с потолка взятые утверждения, что "шти на Руси известны **как минимум** с VIII века, когда крестьяне начали выращивать капусту". Без намёка на источник. Ну и потом уже просто "факты" из категории "известно, что...", "очевидно, что.." и "по мнению ряда учёных".

Так появляются статьи в блогах, которые цитируются в фэйсбуке, откуда они попадают в онлайн-журналы и, глядишь, через месяц-два появляется статья в блоге, цитирующая (в качестве подтверждения истинности) один из таких онлайн-журналов. И все при деле.

Comment: Помои (забавно) — то блюдо, которым потчуют коровушек, коз и прочую скотинку сельские жители.

Comment: @shampar А вы ничего не путаете? За весь русский язык не скажу, но в наших краях скотина помои не ест :)

Comment: Любая скатинка поблагодарит за овощи от слова ПОМЫТЬ, замешанные на молоке. В ваших краях, видимо, из не моют.

Comment: @shampar Да нет, в наших краях просто скотина неблагодарная ) Действительно, нашлась (после долгих поисков) фраза "Помои скармливайте только в свежем виде.", в статье про коров. Материал из Томской обл.  В наших краях (а я вырос в сельской местности, и скотину мы держали) на такую фразу покрутили бы у виска :) Помои у нас - в помойном ведре(бадье), что под умывальником, и их выливают "на помойке". Пищ.отходы там тоже могут быть, но даже свинья это есть не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, щи изначально обозначало не суп, а некий напиток наподобие кваса.
Название восходит к древнерусскому "съто" (ср. "сытый", "сытный").

Во-вторых, множественное число - историко-филологический казус, не имеющий, видимо, исчерпывающего рационального объяснения. Иностранцам это лучше всего принять как данность, как и очень многое в русском, объяснению на примитивах не поддающееся.

Единственное, что можно предположить, это переосмысление формы "сътый", которое с падением редуцированных превратилось в "сты", а уже их него в "щи". Но это не более чем умозрительная версия. Подтверждений нет.

ПС.
Я бы не ставил щи в один ряд с такими pluralia tantum как "белила", "чернила" или "румяна". И даже "помои". В последнем есть оттенок обычной собирательности, а в первых трех - собирательности инструментальной. А вот "щи" это исключает, поскольку изначальное значение ничего такого не предполагало.

Comment: Добавил пару ссылок в вопрос. А @GalinaAvanesova - спасибо за исправления, писал с планшета в полусне :)

Comment: @Michael_1812 Вы серьезно уверены, что слово "щи" придумала хозяйка с котлом? Тогда вынужден вас разочаровать. Слово "щи" (уже во множественном числе!) появилось задолго до вашей хозяйки и означало кислый напиток, изготовление которого не то что "наличных" овощей, но и самое котла не предполагал.

Comment: @Michael_1812 Думается, что истина, как обычно, может быть где-то посередине... Хочется слегка углубиться, и повертеть тему с разных сторон. Как ув. behemothus объясняет перенос наименования с какого-то "кислого напитка" на нынешний "капустный суп"?  `Иностранцам это лучше всего принять как данность` - да бог с ними, с иностранцами, считайте, что она русская.   `А вот "щи" это исключает` - не слишком сильное утверждение? Учитывая, что всё, что нам известно по вопросу, по-прежнему остается в статусе гипотезы и не более...